# Problemas ao criar backup do Postgre no Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Não encontrei muitas informações sobre a criação de backups do Postgre com C#, por isso, criei esse post. O processo é simples... Estou criando um processo que executa um comando e passa alguns parâmetros só que tudo está sendo executado sem erros, mas o backup não está sendo criado... No meu AppSettings, estou guardando os parâmetros e passando para a função usando a classe BackupRestore... Já testei de tudo e não funciona. Alguém tem alguma solução ou até mesmo alguma forma diferente se se fazer backup?

```
"DataConnection": {
    "Servidor": "localhost",
    "Porta": "5432",
    "Usuario": "postgres",
    "Senha": "334522",
    "NomeBancoDados": "Retaguarda",
    "DiretorioComando": "C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\11\\bin",
    "DiretorioBackup": "C:\\Users\\JALBER\\Downloads\\",
    "NomeArquivo": "Backup_Retaguarda_"
  }

public void CreateBackup(BackupRestore backupRestore)
{
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PGPASSWORD", backupRestore.Senha);

    string backupFile = backupRestore.DiretorioBackup + backupRestore.NomeArquivo + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy") + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM") + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd") + ".backup";
    string BackupString = "-ibv -Z3 -f \"" + backupFile + "\" " +
     "-Fc -h " + backupRestore.Servidor + " -U " + backupRestore.Usuario + " -p " + backupRestore.Porta + " " + backupRestore.NomeBancoDados;

    Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = backupRestore.DiretorioComando + "\\pg_dump.exe";
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = BackupString;

    proc.Start();
    proc.WaitForExit();
    proc.Close();
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Verifiquei em um site algo que possa ajudar...

Primeiro checa o postgre

```
bool bPostgresService = false;
ServiceController[] services = ServiceController.GetServices();
// try to find service name
foreach (ServiceController service in services)
{
    if (service.ServiceName.Contains("postgre") == true)
    {
        bPostgresService = true;
        break;
    }
              }
if (bPostgresService == true)
{
    PG_DumpExePath();
    objProcess.Kill();
    if (sbPG_dumpPath.Length != 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Your System is INSATALLED with Postgres");
        labelLocation.Text = "Installation Location is " + strInstallLocation;
        labelLocation.Visible = true;
                 btnCheckPostgres.BackColor = Color.Green;
        panel1.Enabled = true;
    }

}
else
{
    objProcess.Kill();
    MessageBox.Show("Your System is NOT INSATALLED with Postgres");
}
```

Para esta função, forneça o nome do arquivo como argumento de entrada e a função procurará o arquivo em todas as unidades e retornará o local do arquivo. A performFileSearchTaskfunção é uma função de pesquisa de arquivos iterativa .

```
private string LookForFile(string strFileName)
{
    string strPG_dumpPath = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

        foreach (DriveInfo drive in drives)
        {
            strPG_dumpPath = performFileSearchTask(drive.Name, strFileName);
            if (strPG_dumpPath.Length != 0)
                break;
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
      { }
    return strPG_dumpPath;
}

private string performFileSearchTask(string dirName, string strfileName)
{
    try
    {
        if (strPG_dumpPath.Length == 0)
        {
            try
            {

                foreach (string ddir in Directory.GetDirectories(dirName))
                {
                    System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission ReadPermission =
                        new System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission(
                        System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermissionAccess.Write, ddir);
                    if (System.Security.SecurityManager.IsGranted(ReadPermission))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            foreach (string dfile in Directory.GetFiles(ddir, strfileName))
                            {
                                strPG_dumpPath = ddir + "\\";
                                if (strPG_dumpPath.Length > 0)
                                {
                                    strInstallLocation = strPG_dumpPath;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            if (strPG_dumpPath.Length == 0)
                                performFileSearchTask(ddir, strfileName);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        { }
                    }
                    if (strPG_dumpPath != string.Empty)
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { }

        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { }
    return strPG_dumpPath;
}
```

Se o sistema estiver instalado com o banco de dados Postgres, somente as opções de Backup / Restauração serão fornecidas pelo aplicativo. A próxima operação necessária é clicar no botão "Obter todos os bancos de dados". Ao lado deste botão, a caixa de texto do número da porta é fornecida para inserir o número da porta desejada para procurar os bancos de dados (no meu caso, é 5432).

```
try
{
    comboBox1.Items.Clear();
    comboBox1.Text = string.Empty;
    DataSet dsDB = new DataSet();
    strPort = txtPort.Text;
    strConnection = "Server=localhost;Port=" + strPort + 
      ";Database=postgres;Userid=postgres;Password=postgres;";

    dsDB = GetData("SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE " + 
      "datistemplate IS FALSE AND datallowconn IS TRUE AND datname!='postgres';");
    if (dsDB != null)
    {
        if (dsDB.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dsDB.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(dsDB.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString());
            }
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            strDatabaseName = comboBox1.Text;
            butSelectLoc.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Database is existing");
            }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{ }
```

Após a conclusão desta função, a caixa de combinação é atualizada com os bancos de dados Postgres disponíveis. O usuário tem permissão para selecionar o banco de dados na caixa de combinação para a qual a operação de Backup / Restauração é executada.

Para fazer o backup você deve selecionar o local onde deseja salvar o arquivo de backup clicando no botão “Selecionar o local para salvar o arquivo de backup”. Após a seleção, a caixa de texto abaixo do botão é atualizada com o local do arquivo de backup. O formato do arquivo de backup é DbName_Backup_Date_HoursMin.Backup.

Em seguida, o usuário pode clicar no botão "Fazer backup do banco de dados". Nessa função, o script necessário para a operação de backup é formado como um arquivo em lotes e é executado como um processo.

```
private void butBackup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "-------")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Select the location to save");
            return;
        }
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("DBBackup.bat");
        // Do not change lines / spaces b/w words.
        StringBuilder strSB = new StringBuilder(strPG_dumpPath);

        if (strSB.Length != 0)
        {
            strSB.Append("pg_dump.exe --host " + strServer + " --port " + strPort + 
              " --username postgres --format custom --blobs --verbose --file ");
            strSB.Append("\"" + textBox1.Text + "\"");
            strSB.Append(" \"" + strDatabaseName + "\r\n\r\n");
            sw.WriteLine(strSB);
            sw.Dispose();
            sw.Close();
            Process processDB = Process.Start("DBBackup.bat");
            do
            {//dont perform anything
            }
            while (!processDB.HasExited);
            {
                MessageBox.Show(strDatabaseName + " Successfully Backed up at " + textBox1.Text);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Provide the Location to take Backup!");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { }
}
```

Esta é a função necessária para formar a strPG_dumpPathstring. Esta cadeia é comum para as funções de backup e restauração. Fornecemos o caminho do pg_dump.exe necessário para as operações de backup e restauração.

```
private void PG_DumpExePath()
{
    try
    {
        // Do not change lines / spaces b/w words.
        if (sbPG_dumpPath.Length == 0)
        {
            //string strPG_dumpPath = string.Empty;
            if (strPG_dumpPath == string.Empty)
            {
                strPG_dumpPath = LookForFile("pg_dump.exe");
                if (strPG_dumpPath == string.Empty)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Postgres is not installed");
                }
            }

            int a = strPG_dumpPath.IndexOf(":\\", 0);
            a = a + 2;
            string strSub = strPG_dumpPath.Substring(0, (a - 2));
            strPG_dumpPath = strPG_dumpPath.Substring(a, (strPG_dumpPath.Length - a));

            StringBuilder sbSB1 = new StringBuilder(strPG_dumpPath);
            sbSB1.Replace("\\", "\r\n\r\ncd ");

            StringBuilder sbSB2 = new StringBuilder("cd /D ");
            sbSB2.Append(strSub);
            sbSB2.Append(":\\");

            sbSB1 = sbSB2.Append(sbSB1);
            sbSB1 = sbSB1.Remove((sbSB1.Length - 3), 3);
            sbPG_dumpPath = sbSB1;
            strPG_dumpPath = sbSB1.ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { }
}
```

Após a conclusão da operação de backup, o arquivo de backup de saída é criado para o local selecionado.

Esta é a principal informação de como fazer o backup, caso queira o link completo do artigo ...

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/360472/Postgres-Database-Backup-Restore-From-Csharp

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/231047)

Comment: Ok, obgd... sou novo nesta plataforma

Comment: irei alterar o comentario